# Veracrypt is taking forever to mount a partition (Ubuntu 18.04.01 LTS)

Tags: mount, veracrypt

I had recently installed Ubuntu 18.04.01 LTS (OS Type: 64 bit) everything works fine except Veracrypt. which takes forever to mount a drive. Once I waited to see exactly how much time it takes to mount but after serveral hours i still got the Please wait.

I had also tried starting veracrypt as sudo and then mounting a partition but it the same.

Anyway strange thing happened. On windows I installed veracrypt latest version (VeraCrypt Setup 1.23-Hotfix-2.exe) and it mounted the drive in seconds (actually it first asked that the drive is unclean and it will clean it, after that it mounted the drive.

I now know in Ubuntu I can mount the volume through console using

```
veracrypt -t --mount /mnt/backup/temp/dll /media/veracrypt1
```

Comment: It still toke a long time to mount the drive through console (don't know exactly how long but surely it was in minutes instead of hours but at least some what satisfied to access the encrypted partitions). 

If someone could only tell me where the veracrypt logs are to see them and know a little bit more about the underlying problem(s).

Comment: I had noticed some freak behavior of Veracrypt. Although it had mounted the first mount without delay but it is taking a 6 mins to mount the second mount. Maybe if anybody will share where Veracrypt log files are kept; Maybe it will shed some light on the underlying problem

Comment: found an maybe interesting info. Where unmount veracrypt drives by `veracrypt -d` got this error message 
**Gtk-Message: 13:23:56.777: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"**

Comment: Misc useful info for linux Veracrypt users **Mount a volume prompting only for its password:**
`veracrypt -t -k "" --protect-hidden=no --mount /mnt/backup/temp/dll /media/veracrypt1`

**Dismount a volume:**
`veracrypt -d volume.tc`

**Dismount all mounted volumes:**
`veracrypt -d`

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 18.04 (gnome 3.2.82), I couldn't get Veracrypt to load a volume using the gnome app menu (the square of dots). But I discovered several other ways to get it working without any long-winded commands or even tricks.

1. Terminal: "sudo -H nautilus" then went to "Other Locations" then usr/share/applications/veracrypt and it worked fine to load volume.
2. Terminal (non-root): "nautilus" worked fine to load volume.
3. Favorites Bar on Desktop: Veracrypt link worked fine to load volume.

For all cases above, I DID NOT mount from the Main Veracrypt Menu. I did the following:

1. I selected the volume
2. I clicked the "Mount" button but went to "Options" in the lower right corner.
3. I had to check the TrueCrypt Volume box for my particular situation.
4. I entered the volume's password at the top of the same window.
5. I DID NOT have to select "Do Not Mount" by the way.
6. I clicked on "OK" to start the mounting process.
7. I then entered my user password for Ubuntu to give it sudo permissions.
8. The volume mounted within 1 minute and appeared in Nautilus under "Other Locations."

I retried the above steps using the gnome app menu link (square of dots), but it still did not work. Therefore, this is a solution and a problem in one post. I hope it helps others!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I had found a temporary solution (remember its just a way around and not the exact solution), You had to mount the encrypted drive in virtualbox in Windows (e.g. win 8). There you can work without a hitch. I know it a long shot but it serve the purpose.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.10 Cosmic seem to have no such problem.